# If last child, do something else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping through a series of images, passing the class `.current` along a series of elements, and cloning it each time. Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/EMFZe/3/

Note: I'm using `.img` as a placeholder for `img`.

```
$('.next').click(function(){

    $('.main-frame').empty();
    if (!$('.slide-controller .slide.current').is(':last')) {

        $('.current')
        .removeClass('current')
        .next()
        .addClass('current')
        .clone('.img')
        .appendTo('.main-frame');
    } else { 
        alert('else!'); // this is never called
    }
});
```

**Problem**: The if statement does not seem to be working correctly: the `else` is never called. Would anyone know why?

(Eventually, when the `.current` is on the last child, I need to reverse the slideshow)

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying last of what... try

```
$('.slide-controller .slide.current').is('.slide-controller .slide:last')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f2G5E/1/)

Or check for :last-child

```
$('.slide-controller .slide.current').is(':last-child')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f2G5E/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I think I answered this first in the comments above but no biggie if you accept someone else's answer first.

```
Change :last to :last-child
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EMFZe/4/

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between using `:last` and `:last-child` in this instance?

Comment: From the jQuery docs it says that :last is used to "Reduce the set of matched elements to the final one in the set" while :last-child "Selects all elements that are the last child of their parent.".

Comment: Okay, I'm a little confused as to why `:last` wasn't working; was it not the last of it's set?

Comment: My comment above was wrong. :last definition is that it "Selects the last matched element". I'm a bit fuzzy on what the exact difference is myself tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Change `last` for `last-child` and all should be well:

http://jsfiddle.net/EMFZe/6/

`if (!$('.slide-controller .slide.current').is(':last-child')) {`